# SGI STL Rope in g++?

Tags: c++, stl, libstdc++, sgi, ropes

It seems that there is a implementation of rope in my `/usr/include/c++/4.5.1/ext/rope` (and `ropeimpl.h`). I compared it with SGI STL and the code seems to be pretty much the same codebase.

I'm not aware of its status or if its functional or not. Nor i am aware if this is super old stale code, or code in progress

in any case, i haven't found any references about how to use it (if functional). Do you know something i'm missing? are there usage examples i can use?

**EDIT** if you see the [cvs history here](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/), you'll see last activity was 4 months ago, which doesn't look like pretty active, but doesn't look abandoned either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's taken straight from the SGI code, and is still maintained (I [changed](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-06/msg00039.html) it just the other day to fix a longstanding bug) but is only documented briefly with the [deprecated extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_sgi.html).

Answer (score -1):

I haven't looked at ropes since the nineties, but the SGI STL documentation for [`rope<T, Alloc>`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html) is still on-line. Also [The Rope Implementation Overview](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ropeimpl.html).

Comment: yeah i know about that, this is what i compared it against.

Comment: No longer online now. (besides your answer seems link-only)